# Deployment failed. Connection can't be made. Ensure server is running. To update/ change server, enter name of the server in the project properties

Tags: sql-server

I checked the list of services, SQL server, SQL server agent, SQL server browser are running. But I don't have integration, analysis, reporting services in my list of services even after installing the extensions from VS. Am using VS 2019, SQL server 2019 of developer edition and SSMS 18. I also have SQL server data tools installed in my VS. After reading the error msg I also changed the server name in the project properties from 'localhost' to '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB', also replaced it with IP address. But nothing worked. I think it is due to no SSAS, SSIS, SSRS in the services list. How can I get them into my list. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to deploy here?

Comment: I created a simple dimension in SSAS project and trying to deploy the project. I just started learning how to design BI solutions.

Comment: Also, if you're using `localdb` Then none of those services are relevant. `localdb` is a very trimmed down version of SQL Server for (as it's name suggests) for local use. It doesn't support Agent, nor remote connections.

Comment: If you want to deploy SSAS then you need to install SSAS; from your post it suggests you have not.

Comment: I installed SSAS from the extensions in Visual studio 2019.

Comment: That's not installing SSAS... You've installed the a development extension for Visual Studio to create SSAS projects. Much like installing SSMS isn't installing SQL Server and installing a game means you've installed your entire steam library (unless, I suppose, you only have 1 game).

Comment: Why I'm not able to get those 3 services (SSIS, SSAS, SSRS) in my SQL server configuration manager? Can you please help me how to get them added into my list of services? How can I check whether they are installed or not?

Comment: You need the *install* those services for them to be available. When you installed SQL Server you either installed a version that doesn't support them (Express) or didn't explicitly select to install them.

Comment: Can you please provide me the links to install those services and get them added into my existing SQL server

Comment: Use the same installer as you did before.

Comment: I installed developer edition of SQL server.

Comment: And *just* data engine, by the sounds of it; hence the problem. Like I've said, to deploy an SSAS Project you first need SSAS installed and the service running...

Comment: Thank you. The error was resolved after installing SSAS into the SQL server.